# Service workers fetch event listener: what does it catch?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, service-worker

I have an issue with catching fetch events from a service worker.

In a page at `https://localhost/subdir/page.php` I register the service worker with:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('https://localhost/subdir/sw.js', {scope: './'}).then( ... );
```

I then register the Fetch event listener with:

```
this.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) { ... });
```

In the same page at `https://localhost/subdir/page.php` I then have four different kinds of links:

```
<a href="https://localhost/subdir/page2.php">link1</a><br />
<a href="http://localhost/subdir/page2.php">link2</a><br />
<a href="https://otherhost">link3</a><br />
<a href="http://otherhost">link4</a><br />
```

I noticed that the service worker only catches the fetch event from link1, leaving the other three unnoticed.

Every test I made seems to suggest that the service worker gets notified only for requests going to its own origin.
Can anyone confirm this?
Any known workaround?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you seeing that same behavior in multiple browsers? In Firefox as well as in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, both in Firefox 53.0.2 (Linux) and Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's how it's supposed to work for navigations. You shouldn't be able to intercept the user going to a different site. (You do get access to all subresource requests of the document, regardless of origin.)

Comment: Thank you @Anne for the clarification!
You say that it shouldn't be able to intercept requests to different sites, but my tests seem to indicate that it does not intercept request to the same site, but with different protocol (i.e. different origin). Can you confirm this?

Comment: Yeah, only same-origin navigations can be intercepted. (And with those, you're also subject to scope rules which depend on where in the directory structure your service worker is located or depend on a response header on the service worker.)

Comment: Thank you. I tried the `Service-Worker-Allowed` header but it doesn't seem to help. Actually what I am trying to do is registering a service worker (from `https://a.com`) able to intercept requests to `http://a.com` fired by clicking links on a page hosted at `http://a.com`. Do you think this is feasible somehow?

Comment: No as I said that's not possible. Only same-origin can be intercepted.

Comment: As a further comment, don't use HTTP. Redirect all traffic to HTTPS, and configure HSTS and HSTS preloading to make sure all future visits go to HTTPS automatically.